# Get the right data for a specific id

Tags: sql, sorting, mariadb

I want to get the prices for each product for a specific place. Here's what I have done so far.

```
SELECT pl.id AS place_id,
pl.data_name AS place_name,
pp.data_price AS product_price,
pp.date_updated AS price_updated

FROM places AS pl
JOIN products AS pr
ON pl.id = pr.id_place
JOIN products_prices AS pp
WHERE pp.id_product = '30'
GROUP BY pl.id, pp.data_price, pp.date_updated
ORDER BY pp.data_price DESC, pp.date_updated DESC
```

[image]

As you can see from the image above, `product_price` and `price_updated` are all the same. `place_name` also shows 3 places that does not have the product with id 30.

Here's how it should looks like (cheapest, most recent product purchase on top):

```
place_id    place_name        product_price    price_updated
       3    ICA Maxi                   4.95    2018-05-16
       1    ICA Supermarket            5.90    2018-05-27
      26    ICA Skutan                 6.50    2018-05-29
```

Here's the database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `places` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `data_address` text,
  `data_address_city` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `data_coordinates` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `places` (`id`, `data_name`, `data_address`, `data_address_city`, `data_coordinates`) VALUES
    (1, 'ICA Supermarket', 'Björkhagsgatan 9', 'Skoghall', '59.324971,13.467291'),
    (2, 'ICA Maxi', 'Bergviks Köpcentrum', 'Karlstad', '59.376563,13.428787'),
    (3, 'ICA Kvantum', 'Bivägen 11', 'HammarÃ¶', '59.343388,13.504583'),
    (4, 'IKEA', 'Bergviksvägen 43', 'Karlstad', '59.379032,13.420646'),
    (5, 'Karlstad Naprapatklinik', 'Västra Torggatan 15', 'Karlstad', '59.381379,13.501683'),
    (9, 'BesÃ¶k i Borgvik AB', '', 'Borgvik', '59.348261,12.954707'),
    (23, 'Mariebergsskogen', '', 'Karlstad', '59.369403,13.486485'),
    (24, 'Happy Price', 'Brehogsvägen 20', 'Tanumshede', '58.723730,11.344768'),
    (25, 'Trekanten KÃ¶k & Bar', 'Parkvägen 2', 'Hamburgsund', '58.552733,11.270998'),
    (26, 'ICA Skutan', 'Strandvägen', 'Hamburgsund', '58.552122,11.270898');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_place` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_barcode` text NOT NULL,
  `data_name` text NOT NULL,
  `data_weight` text NOT NULL,
  `data_weight_type` text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `id_place`, `data_barcode`, `data_name`, `data_weight`, `data_weight_type`) VALUES
    (7, 3, '7311070008494', 'Pågen Lantbröd', '650', 'g'),
    (8, 3, '7310618084808', 'Grumme citronsåpa', '750', 'ml'),
    (9, 3, '7318690079835', 'ICA Basic toalettpapper', '', ''),
    (12, 1, '7318690134640', 'ICA Basic Milk & Caramel', '100', 'g'),
    (18, 3, '7310380512103', 'ICA Home dishmatic refillsvamp', '', ''),
    (19, 3, '7340109200684', 'Plastkasse', '', ''),
    (20, 1, '7310751163903', 'ICA tonfisk filébitar i vatten', '185', 'g'),
    (24, 1, '7310865001818', 'Arla mellanmjölk', '1.5', 'kg'),
    (25, 1, '7318690079712', 'ICA kattsand (klumpbildande, ej parfym)', '6', 'kg'),
    (29, 26, '3068320055008', 'Evian mineralvatten', '500', 'mL'),
    (30, 26, '7318690134640', 'ICA Basic Milk & Caramel', '100', 'g'),
    (33, 2, '0', 'ICA Basic Milk & Caramel', '100', 'g');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_transaction` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `data_amount` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `data_discount` tinytext,
  `data_discount_amount` tinytext,
  `data_discount_sum` tinytext,
  `data_pant` tinytext,
  `date_updated` date NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `products_prices` (`id`, `id_product`, `id_transaction`, `data_price`, `data_amount`, `data_discount`, `data_discount_amount`, `data_discount_sum`, `data_pant`, `date_updated`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 907, 18.90, '4', '', '2', '30', NULL, '2018-05-18'),
    (2, 12, 907, 4.90, '4', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-18'),
    (5, 4, 904, 18.90, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-18'),
    (6, 14, 904, 14.90, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-18'),
    (17, 19, 936, 2.00, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-21'),
    (18, 21, 947, 23.90, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-23'),
    (19, 22, 947, 10.50, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-23'),
    (20, 20, 947, 15.90, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-23'),
    (21, 13, 947, 49.90, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-23'),
    (22, 23, 948, 14.90, '1', '', '', '', NULL, '2018-05-24'),
    (23, 24, 961, 14.90, '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-05-27'),
    (24, 12, 961, 5.90, '4', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-05-27'),
    (32, 28, 967, 8.50, '2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-05-28'),
    (33, 29, 972, 12.90, '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', '2018-05-29'),
    (34, 30, 973, 6.50, '2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-05-29'),
    (35, 31, 976, 10.00, '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-05-30'),
    (36, 32, 976, 10.00, '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-05-30');
```

Comment: The `ON` clause for `JOIN products_prices` is missing. (That is invalid SQL, but you are probably using MySQL which lets this slip, converting the inner join silently into a cross join. An awful thing to do in my opinion. MySQL should throw an error instead.)

Comment: Please post the data set and desired result set

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: If I add `ON pr.id = pp.id_product` under `JOIN products_prices AS pp`, it will only show 1 row: the row about ICA Skutan.

Comment: @JoeTaras: You mean all the data I have in my database for those tables, with the result?

Comment: Yes, some data to fill your posted table structures

Comment: Please show sample input data so that we don't have to keep guessing here.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` if you're not aggregating on anything?

Comment: Syntax error... Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @JoeTaras: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I use `GROUP BY` because I was testing some methods

Comment: @jarlh: I use MariaDB, if that was your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment to your request: You forgot the `ON` clause that links the `products_prices` table to the other two.

MariaDB nastily converts your inner join into a cross join instead of raising an error as it should. What this gives you is: select all prices for product 30 combined with all places multiplied with the number of products therein, instead of just combined with the product's place.

By the way: I'd put table `products` first in the `FROM` clause, because this is the base (you want product 30). Then join the product's prices and the product's place.

There is no reason to group your data, as you only want to list the prices. You are not aggregating anything. So you get:

```
SELECT 
  pl.id AS place_id,
  pl.data_name AS place_name,
  pp.data_price AS product_price,
  pp.date_updated AS price_updated
FROM products AS pr
JOIN products_prices AS pp ON pp.id_product = pr.id
JOIN places pl ON pl.id = pr.id_place
WHERE pr.id = 30
ORDER BY pp.data_price DESC, pp.date_updated DESC;
```

Comment: Oh. I had no idea that MariaDB converts inner join to cross join. You learn things each day ^^, Thanks!

Comment: The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` and `CROSS` are ignored in MySQL/MariaDB.  The `ON`/`WHERE` controls which you actually get.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT PL.id AS place_id,
PL.data_name AS place_name,
PP.data_price AS product_price,
PP.date_updated AS price_updated
FROM products_prices PP
JOIN products PR
    ON PR.id = PP.id_product
JOIN places PL
    ON PL.id = PR.id_place
WHERE PR.id = '30'
```

Comment: `SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'PP.id_place' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @Erik: query fixed

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix it. But it only shows one place out of 3 places. `WHERE PI.id = '30'` maybe is to specific?

Comment: @Erik: With your data set exists only one product with ID 30 associated to one place. Maybe I don't understand your aim.

Comment: @Erik: I agree with Joe. There is only one place per product (because the product table record contains one place reference only), and you are only selecting one product (namely product 30). So how can you expect three different places?

Comment: The problem lies at myself :) I can't think straight in this heat (approx. +29 C in the shadow, which is record in Sweden during this time of the year). Your codes works perfectly as the attempt I did shows. Do you guys have any quick solution that solves how I think and want it to be? I will otherwise try for myself more :)

Comment: @Erik: Yes, have a cold shower ;-) I think you should just accept the answer, because your original issue is solved. Then think about why you expect three places. What do you have in mind that leads to three places. Three particular place names? Three specific products? Products with certain current prices? ...

Comment: Haha! So true ;) Yeah. You have right about that. I've accepted your answer, since it was rich on information. Many thanks for your comment! I want to get the lowest and more recent prices on top and the highest and recent prices at the bottom. Will focus on that. Thanks once again :)